# Make Gradle resolve my library's maven url automatically

Tags: android, maven, gradle, bintray, jcenter

My library is on Jcenter. To import it as a Gradle dependency, one must also manually specify the repository's URL like this in the receiving project's build.gradle :

```
  repositories {
       
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url  "https://dl.bintray.com/fabricethilaw/sonarnet"
        }
    }
```

How to configure my library in order to make it resolved with **only** the Gradle `implementation com.fabricethilaw.sonarnet:core:xxx`?

---

**UPDATE ABOUT JCENTER**

I have checked on Bintray and it looks like my library is already approved on JCenter.

[image]

Maybe I am missing something in order to help people get not to have to add
`maven { url  "https://dl.bintray.com/fabricethilaw/sonarnet"  }`, when they import the library in Gradle

Comment: You have all that is necessary already. What is not working? Any errors? Which ones?

Comment: It's working fine. But I see many libraries online that do not require to set the "maven { url <something> }" part in the project gradle file before being resolved. All you do is to add the dependency with 'implementation' tag. 

I would like it to be the same with my library

Comment: Your library is not in Jcenter its in bintray.

Comment: @ThilawFabrice Those libraries are probaby in jcenter or MavenCentral.